# Preg_match identifier

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I want ot get a match from my identifier.

I have a string like this coming in `{/describe:foo}` where I am trying to
match `{/describe:}` to return `foo`, but am not getting the regex right, would
someone mind pointing out what I did wrong? here's my match.

```
$regexp = '/\{describe:(.*?)\}/i';
$query  = '{/describe:foo}'; 
preg_match($regexp, $query, $match);

print_r($match); // (bool) false
```

**Background**
I hope this can help others, a good reason to do this is to create replaceable
control words in a string that can be interpreted and replaced, here's an example
of a RESTful poster that will run a descriptor on a control word.

```
  if (preg_match('/\{describe:(.*?)\}/i', $_POST['query'], $match))
  {
        // Describe Salesforce Object from internal POST tool
        print_r($SforceConnection->describeSObjects($match[1]));
        exit;
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the forward slash in your regexp:

```
$regexp = '/\{\/describe:(.*?)\}/i';
```

or:

```
$regexp = '#\{/describe:(.*?)\}#i';
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$regexp = '/\{\/describe\:(.*?)\}/i';
$query  = '{/describe:foo}';
preg_match($regexp, $query, $match);

print_r($match); // Array ( [0] => {/describe:foo} [1] => foo )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$regexp = '#{/describe:([^}]+)}#i';
$query  = '{/describe:foo}'; 
preg_match($regexp, $query, $match);

print_r($match);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest terms your could use this: `(?<=\/describe:).*(?=})`

Comment: Throws an `unknown modifier .` just a heads up

Comment: I don't usually consider lookarounds to be "the simplest" :)

Comment: @Adrian - True... I was more going for just grabbing a full match, no sub-pattern.

Comment: @ehime - interesting... i ran it through RegExr, but didn't actually run it through PHP.

Comment: @Daedalus that might be the problem, I know PHP's flavor of regex is PCRE which might have affected the outcome of your query http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php

Answer (score 1):

Try (`/`looks like missing before describe) :

```
$regexp = '/\{/describe:(.*?)\}/i'
```

Comment: The slashes are the regex delimiters and are required (well, some delimiter is required, it doesn't have to be slashes)

Comment: @Adrian Edited my post, there is a missing `/`before `describe` in his regex.